# The Identity theorem - do the accumulation point need to be inside of S or inside of D?

Tags: complex-analysis

**Area:** The Identity Theorem (Complex Analysis)

Let D be a non-empty, connected open subset of the Complex Plane and let f be analytic on D. Then the following three statements are equivalent.

1. f(z) = 0 for all z in D.
2. The set $ S = \{z\in D\mid f(z)=0\}$ **contains** an accumulation point.
3. There exists a point $z_0 \in D$ such that $f^{(n)}(z_0) = 0 \ $ for all $n \geq 0$.

**Question:** I have been wondering about the second statement. Some sources state that the accumulation point of the set S needs to be contained inside of S meanwhile others just state that it needs to be contained inside of D. Which one is right?

**I think that this theorem comes from the following:** If f is analytic on a domain D and is not equal to zero on the whole domain then the zeros of f is discrete in D. Hence the set of all zeroes for an analytic function are isolated and the set of them can therefore not have a limit point (accumulation point). The only way the set of all zeros (S in the identity theorem) can have a limit point would be if the function is equal to 0 on the whole domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some sources state that the accumulation point of the set S needs to be contained inside of S meanwhile others just state that it needs to be contained inside of D.

It makes no difference. If $S = \{z\in D\mid f(z)=0\}$ has an accumulation point $z_0 \in D$ then $f(z_0) = 0$ because $f$ is continuous, so that $z_0 \in S$.

Comment: My interpretation of the second statement of the theorem was that the set S doesn't need to contain **all** zeroes of the function just some of them and therefore I'm not sure if I understand how the point necessary needs to be inside of S. It might be a zero that was not included in the set.

Does that make sense or am I just wrong in my interpretation?

Comment: @JamesBlond The set $S$ as stated in 2. is by definition the set of all zeros not just some.

Comment: @LukasBetz thank you for clarifying. But that means that one must find the set that contains all zeros for the other statements to be true. 

But then the identity theorem for analytic functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem#cite_note-lex2s476-1) seems to say that it is enough to show this for **some** subset for it to be true on the whole domain. This theorem can be proven by using h = f - g = 0 and then applying the identity theorem above for my knowledge.

Comment: @JamesBlond: If you find *some* set $S'$ of zeros with an accumulation point in $D$ then $S \supset S'$ has an accumulation point in $D$ as well. So “$S$ contains an accumulation point” is equivalent to “there is a set of zeros with an accumulation point in $D$.”

Comment: @MartinR ahh - I think I understand now! so as long as I can show that the set $S'$ which contains some zeros has an accumulation point in D then this will of course be true for the set of all zeros since these zeros I found ($S'$) are contained in the set of all zeros.

Thank you for your patience, I have been trying to wrap my head around this theorem for a while now.